# Create a list of dictionaries which contains nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as follows,

```
[{"vehicle_class": "c1", "vehicle_class_count1": 16, "vehicle_usage_count1": 29, "vehicle_usage": "u1", "vehicle_type_count1": 16, "vehicle_type": "t1"}, {"vehicle_class": "c2", "vehicle_class_count1": 11, "vehicle_usage_count1": 29, "vehicle_usage": "u1", "vehicle_type_count1": 11, "vehicle_type": "t1"},{"vehicle_class": "c2", "vehicle_class_count1": 1, "vehicle_usage_count1": 29, "vehicle_usage": "u2", "vehicle_type_count1": 1, "vehicle_type": "t3"},{"vehicle_class": "c3", "vehicle_class_count1": 1, "vehicle_usage_count1": 29, "vehicle_usage": "u2", "vehicle_type_count1": 1, "vehicle_type": "t2"}]
```

from which I want to form a another list of dictionaries as follows,

```
[
                {
                    "name": "u1",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "type": "u1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "t1",
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "type": "t1",
                            "size": 9221
                            "children" : [
                                    {"name": "c1",
                                    "imageURL": "",
                                    "type": "c1",
                                    "size": 9221},
                                    {"name": "c2",
                                    "imageURL": "",
                                    "type": "c2",
                                    "size": 9221}
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "size": 10393
                },
                {
                    "name": "u2",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "type": "u2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "t2",
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "type": "t2",
                            "size": 9221,
                            "children":[
                                    "name": "c3",
                                    "imageURL": "",
                                    "type": "c3",
                                    "size": 9221
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "type": "t3",
                            "name": "t3",
                            "size": 1058,
                            "children": [
                                    "imageURL": "",
                                    "type": "c2",
                                    "name": "c2",
                                    "size": 1058
                            ]
                        }

                    ],
                    "size": 10393
                },

                ]
```

This is what I have tried so far which I was abel to yield half of the expected result.

```
result_dict=[] # The above mentioned list comes here
result_list = []
for i in ['vehicle_usage','vehicle_type','vehicle_class']:  # This is a hierarchy which I assign here dynamically can contain any number of values.
    for item in range(0, len(result_dict)):
        for key,value in result_dict[item].items():
         if key == i:
                if not any(d['name'] == value for d in result_list):
                 result = {}
                 result['name'] = value
                 result['imageURL'] = ''
                 result['type'] = value
                 result['size'] = result_dict[item]['%s_count1' % i]
                 if i != len(result_dict):
                     result['children'] =[]
                 print result
                 result_list.append(result)
print result_list # Final list processed according to the required format.
```

Expected result_list's top level dictionaries must contain `vehicle_usage` distinct values with respective values like `vehicle_usage_count1`.

Second levels (i.e children lists) will contain second level etc. This data is sent to a d3 plugin which requires this format.

Number of levels will rely on number of values come to the

```
['vehicle_usage','vehicle_type','vehicle_class']
```

From my code all the levels are written to the same level. I want them to write to the correct children list.

Comment: Well, your code only try `result_list.append(result)` so obviously, it's all on the same level.

Comment: @abrunet Yes but how can I say to go to the relevant children node?

Comment: You should try having a function to extract the data from your initial dictionnary, iterate one time to extract the first level of data. Then iterate on your created first level, and for each element on your first level, retrieve data from your initial dictionnary etc...

Comment: @abrunet I tried but I failed to go to nth nested list for nth level. I get one dictionary loop n times but I cant go inside of the new dict created searching for correct `children` to insert data. If you dont mind can you post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: I'll try to give you a reall answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from perfection but I think it is working.

```
datalist = [{"vehicle_class": "c1", "vehicle_class_count1": 16, "vehicle_usage_count1": 29, "vehicle_usage": "u1", "vehicle_type_count1": 16, "vehicle_type": "t1"}, {"vehicle_class": "c2", "vehicle_class_count1": 11, "vehicle_usage_count1": 29, "vehicle_usage": "u1", "vehicle_type_count1": 11, "vehicle_type": "t1"},{"vehicle_class": "c2", "vehicle_class_count1": 1, "vehicle_usage_count1": 29, "vehicle_usage": "u2", "vehicle_type_count1": 1, "vehicle_type": "t3"},{"vehicle_class": "c3", "vehicle_class_count1": 1, "vehicle_usage_count1": 29, "vehicle_usage": "u2", "vehicle_type_count1": 1, "vehicle_type": "t2"}]

levels_index = {1: 'vehicle_usage', 2: 'vehicle_type', 3: 'vehicle_class'}


result = []


def build_node(obj, key):
    '''This build the node for your result list'''
    return {
        'name': obj[key],
        'imageURL': '',
        'type': obj[key],
        'size': obj['%s_count1' % key],
        'children': []
    }


def build_level(input_list, keyindex):
    ''' This build one level at a time but call itself recursively'''
    key = levels_index[keyindex]
    levels_memory = {'vehicle_usage': [], 'vehicle_type': [], 'vehicle_class': []}
    output = []
    for obj in input_list:
        if obj[key] not in levels_memory[key]:
            levels_memory[key].append(obj[key])
            output.append(build_node(obj, key))
            if keyindex < len(levels_index):
                output[-1]['children'] = build_level(
                    [_ for _ in input_list if _[key] == output[-1]['name']],
                    keyindex + 1)
    return output


print build_level(datalist, 1)
```

This gives me the following output

```
[
    {
        'children': [
            {
                'children': [
                    {
                        'children': [],
                        'imageURL': '',
                        'type': 'c1',
                        'name': 'c1',
                        'size': 16
                    }, {
                        'children': [],
                        'imageURL': '',
                        'type': 'c2',
                        'name': 'c2',
                        'size': 11
                    }],
                'imageURL': '',
                'type': 't1',
                'name': 't1',
                'size': 16}],
        'imageURL': '',
        'type': 'u1',
        'name': 'u1',
        'size': 29
    }, {
        'children': [{
            'children': [],
            'imageURL': '',
            'type': 't3',
            'name': 't3',
            'size': 1
        }, {
            'children': [{
                'children': [],
                'imageURL': '',
                'type': 'c3',
                'name': 'c3',
                'size': 1
            }],
            'imageURL': '',
            'type': 't2',
            'name': 't2',
            'size': 1
        }],
        'imageURL': '',
        'type': 'u2', 
        'name': 'u2',
        'size': 29
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your time and effort. It works. But there's a minor issue like [{c1-->c2-->c3},{d1-->d2-->c3}] or [{c1-->c2-->c3},{d1-->c2-->d3}] the duplicated value wont come to the necessary place in two places Instead it comes to the first dictionary only. Then the above mentioned list will appear as [{c1-->c2-->c3},{d1-->d2-->null}] or [{c1-->c2-->c3},{d1-->null-->null}] . I think it wont add to the `levels_memory` since its already added.

Comment: I edited the code. `levels_memory` is initialized in the `build_level` function. Tell me if it is ok now =)